# How do i do foreach loop in array inside an array in CakePHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, cakephp-2.3

I have a variable for eg: `$Foods`, which stores arrays like:

```
array(
    'Fruit' => 'Banana',
    'cake' => array(
        (int) 0 => '10',
        (int) 1 => '11',
        (int) 2 => '12'
    )
)
```

I want to have this like :

```
array(
    'Fruit' => 'Banana',
    'cake' =>  '10'
)
array(
    'Fruit' => 'Banana',
    'cake' =>  '11'
)
 array(
    'Fruit' => 'Banana',
    'cake' =>  '12'
)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
<?php
        $Foods = array('Fruit' => 'Banana', 'cake' => array('10','11','12'));

        $newFoods = array();
        foreach($Foods['cake'] as $key => $val): 
            $newFoods[$key]['Fruit'] =  $Foods['Fruit'];
            $newFoods[$key]['cake'] =  $val;
        endforeach;

        print_r($newFoods);
    ?>
```

output will be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Fruit] => Banana
            [cake] => 10
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Fruit] => Banana
            [cake] => 11
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Fruit] => Banana
            [cake] => 12
        )

)
```